# Proper design to lead user to setting to turn on permission and to return to app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I've done a lot of research online and its I couldn't find anything on how to handle the following situation:

1. User denies the permission the first time to get their location.
2. User tries to get location, see's rationale box, and goes to settings to turn on the location
3. If the user turns on the settings and presses back, what is the best way to determine if user accepted or denied the permission and how to continue the code once the user returns from the setting screen?

Lastly, is there a specific way to go directly to the location settings permission for my application?

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        checkPermissions()
    }

    private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ) {
        onPermissionResult()
    }

    private val PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    )

    private fun arePermissionsGranted() : Boolean {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun werePermissionsDenied() : Boolean {
        return shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            || shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
    }

    private fun checkPermissions() {
        if (arePermissionsGranted()) {
            getCurLoc()
        } else if (werePermissionsDenied()){
            showDialog()
        } else {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(PERMISSIONS)
        }
    }

    fun showDialog() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setMessage("Location permission is required to download prayer times based" +
            " on your current location.")

        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) { dialog, which ->

            val intent: Intent = Intent(
                Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.fromParts(
                    "package",
                    packageName,
                    null
                )
            ).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
            //here the user goes to settings page. How do we handle when the user returns to the activity? 
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no) { dialog, which ->
            finish()
        }

        builder.show()

    }

    private fun onPermissionResult() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            //do stuff
            getCurLoc()
        } else {
            showPermissionDeniedToast()
            finish()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `denies the permission the first time to get their location` There are several location permissions. You think its irrelevant which one?

Answer (score 0):

Following the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc) about lifecycles.

`onResume()` is the first method called when the user returns to the application with an activity in foreground. The `onResume()` grants the activity is active and ready for the user.

Since `onResume()` is called **every time an activity returns active**, moving from system settings back to the application, falls perfectly for what you are trying to achieve. So yes, use `onResume()` to check if the user has granted permissions.

As far as I know there is no proper method to open directly the application's permissions settings, *maybe I'm wrong* but this was done to ensure the user is 100% aware of the action he is taking, requiring at least 1 manual step.

You can also follow the official [permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) guidelines and best practices for requesting runtime permissions.

EDIT

This is the correct permissions workflow, always from the official documentation, ranging from declaring your permissions, to actually asking the user for permissions.

[image]